# 'on duplicate key update' with some logic

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was working on web scrapping project, which I completed with simple html dom class. Now my client wants me to modify the script to go through the previous results and look for changes (and update them when changes are found). So instead of programming a second script to do the updates, I'm trying to make the original script perform both functions. For example: if a product is already in the database update it using `on duplicate key update`. A second feature the client needs is that he should be able to know if either price or stock are updated.
`on duplicate key update` is fine for updating the fields, but how I can come to know which is updated?

```
mysqli_query($con, "insert into products (id,sku,style,price,stock) values ($id,'$sku','$style',$price,$stock) on duplicate key update set price=values(price), stock=values(stock)")
```

The above query will update price and stock, how I will know if price is update or stock or both? I would like to update other columns based on this as well. For example column name `stock_update` with value 1 as updated, Similarly for price. May be another query?

Please advise
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change your approach.  Keep the historical data, rather than overwriting the data.  So, just insert the new records with their new values and time stamps.  Then use additional logic to get the summaries that you want.

Comment: probably make a second table with the date, price and stock info, use a join to display on frontend, and when you are crawling, add a new entry in the price/stock table - that way you get history (and can make graphs)

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to keep track of the changes in the seperate table, you can then create a new table with ProductId (FK), Stock, Price and modified_date. Use your logic in the code to determine the last changes.